# Reverse osmosis membrane used as an osmosis membrane

Tags: physical-chemistry, osmosis

I recently came across the so-called 'thin-film composite membranes'. They are build up of layers with one of them being semipermeable. As I'm not well versed in chemistry, I'm unsure, if these membranes can be used for standard osmosis too, or if their permeability-property is reliant on the exerted pressure i.e., they allow the flow of water just in one direction.